# dnf refuse to install buildsys-build-rpmfusion-kerneldevpkgs-current

Tags: centos, dnf

dnf complain that kernel-devel version does not match requirement:

```
# dnf install buildsys-build-rpmfusion-kerneldevpkgs-current
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides kernel-devel-uname-r = 4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64 needed by buildsys-build-rpmfusion-kerneldevpkgs-current-11:30-5.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

But actually the correct version is already installed:

```
# dnf list installed | grep kernel-devel
kernel-devel.x86_64                             4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2                            @BaseOS                   
kernel-devel.x86_64                             4.18.0-193.28.1.el8_2                            @BaseOS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't the version that the package requires.

You have:

```
kernel-devel.x86_64                             4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2                                              
kernel-devel.x86_64                             4.18.0-193.28.1.el8_2
```

It is asking for:

```
kernel-devel-4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64
```

Or to put it into the same format:

```
kernel-devel.x86_64                             4.18.0-193.el8
```

What you have is too recent. It wants the `kernel-devel` package release `4.18.0-193` for CentOS 8 but the oldest that you have is release `4.18.0-193.19.1` for CentOS 8.2. This issue can occur with packages from unsupported repos like RPMFusion because dependencies don't always match up with the packages from the supported repos (or other repos that may have been added). If this were just a file that were needed at run time, then you could get around it with a symlink but doing something along those lines in this case could ruin the system by trapping you in dependency hell. Sometimes, packages from those repos just aren't installable for this very reason.

One thing that you could do is to build it from source provided that you can find a version that requires a newer version of `kernel-devel` that you have installed.

Comment: thanks a lot! so I guess I have to build from source

Comment: @Wang See my update. If that's acceptable, then you can accept my answer so that others can reference it.